# Print fields in view using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create  the "Create" view and I need print all fields using razor.

**Model:**

```
 public class SystemViewModel 
{
    public long sys_id { get; set; } = 1;
    [DisplayName("System")]
    public string sys_name { get; set; }
    public string sys_valid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? sys_deleted { get; set; }
    public string sys_location { get; set; }
    public string connection { get; set; }
    public string sys_type { get; set; }
    public bool category_authorization { get; set; }
}
```

I need print all properties to add in there some data. It's cool if use for or foreach  cycle.

I try this, but to much strings...

```
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_id)
    </td>
<tr/>
```

and this is only for one property.

Comment: Mention your problem clearly. It's not clear

Comment: I need to show all fields of my model in view. Just simple: https://www.google.lv/search?q=CREATE+VIEW+IN+C%23+USING+RAZOR&rlz=1C1CHBF_enLV739LV740&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1r8DnxdDTAhUBhSwKHZt9CgEQ_AUICSgC&biw=1922&bih=1072&dpr=1#imgrc=Mwv0sy0cFK__CM:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the reflectin in this situation

```
Properties[] arrProperties=  src.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
foreach(Propeties property in arrProperties)
          property.GetValue(Model, null);
```